# parsererror / SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've searched a lot for this but the answers that I find doesn't work but I think that the problem is mine.

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.status == true) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
if(User::addFavLater($id, $user, 'favs')) {
    $result = array("status" => true);
} else {
    $result = array("status" => false);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

So, this is an excerpt of code that I have and I think can you realising. I want PHP to send a JSON response into JavaScript but this is not happening and JavaScript gives me this error:

```
parsererror / SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I'm using the 2.1.1 version of JQuery.

P.S.: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method `$.ajax`, the success callback receives the response of the server (the JSON file) in the variable `data` (`success:function(data){...}`). Thus, try to recover the value you want from this variable (in your case, something like `data.response` rather than just `response`).

Comment: You should have an error in you PHP file. The server response is then a HTML fragment with the error description and not the expected JSON content. Try to check the data received by the AJAX request in the Network panel of the console.